# Передача данных через ajax post и принять данные на сервер

Tags: php, javascript

view:

```js
$(document). ready(function () {
    $("#country").change(function () {
        var countryval = parseInt( $("#country").val() );
        //console.log(countryval);
        selectRegion(countryval);
    })
})

function selectRegion(countryval) {
    var region = $("#region");

    if (countryval > 0){
        region.fadeIn("slow");
        region.attr("disabled", false);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/index.php?route=account/order/addorder',
            data: 'countryval=' + countryval,
        });

    }
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Область</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select  name="country" id="country">
            <option value="0">- Выберите область -</option>
            <?php foreach ($regions as $region){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $region['id']?>"><?php echo $region['name']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Город</label>
    <div   class="col-sm-10" id="divregion">
        <select disabled id="region" name="region" >
            <option value="">- Выберите город -</option>
            <?php foreach ($oll_city as $city){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $city['id']?>"><?php echo $city['name']?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Подскажите как принимаются данные на сервере, я их отправляю методом post значить они должны прийти в `$_POST`, но когда пытаюсь распечатать `print_r($_POST['countryval'])` получаю ошибку, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` что выдаст?

Comment: Выдает пустой масив

Comment: `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/index.php?route=account/order/addorder',
            data: {countryval: countryval},
        });`
Так тоже пустой?

Comment: Так тоже пустой, а если print_r($_POST['countryval']); выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined index: countryval может форма отправки у меня не правильная, но если посмотреть в консоль  console.log(countryval); то приходят id

Comment: вы как смотрите результат `print_r()`? и что за _ошибку_ получаете? Смотрите в инструментах браузера, что отправляется с xhr-запросом, и там же ответ сервера.

Comment: В браузере в network headers Form data countryval=4 при выборе области у меня приходят id областей я не могу понять почему я в контроллере не могу получить этот id print_r($_POST['countryval']) и мне сразу выдает ошибку Notice: Undefined index: countryval

Comment: Кстати, в $.ajax параметрах последняя запятая лишняя. Может не работать. Ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: Ошибка наверно появляться потому что изначально данных нет, но года  в модель     if(!empty($this->request->post['countryval'])){

           $query =  $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "city WHERE region_id = '" . $this->request->post['countryval'] . "'");

           return $query->rows;

       }  распечатав я получаю массив где выдает id(области) =  id(города) во views выдает ошибку    Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  это за неправильно проварки что то я там напутал

Answer (score 1):

Вот так проверили, всё приходит.

```
$("#country").change(function(){
    var countryval = $("#country[name=country]").val();
    selectRegion(countryval);
})
function selectRegion(countryval){
    if (countryval > 0){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/index.php?route=account/order/addorder',
            data: 'countryval=' + countryval,
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `var countryval = +$("#country").val();`

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь.